# HTML5 Canvas drawing app problem

Tags: html, canvas, paint

I develop html5 drawing app based on canvas. So, now I am coding the brush tool. And have several problems, can anybody gives me link/source example how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

From Dev.Opera: [Creating an HTML 5 canvas painting application](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/)

Please search a bit next time.

Comment: Look, that the example. http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example5.html it doesnt work, i need to start draw on mousedown already(just a dot), and it can draw only when i move mouse, i have the same problem in my code

Comment: @Mark: works for me (in Chrome 12). When I select the “Pencil” drawing tool, it starts drawing on mousedown when I move the mouse.

Comment: But I need to start start drawing onmousedowm without mousemove, just draw a dot.